# List coordinates between a set of coordinates

Tags: python, math, graph

This should be fairly easy, but I'm getting a headache from trying to figure it out. I want to list all the coordinates between two points. Like so:

```
1: (1,1)
2: (1,3)
In between: (1,2)
```

**Or**

```
1: (1,1)
2: (5,1)
In between: (2,1), (3,1), (4,1)
```

It does not need to work with diagonals.

Comment: If this is homework, please add that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle the edge cases, this seems to work:

```
def points_between(p1, p2):
    xs = range(p1[0] + 1, p2[0]) or [p1[0]]
    ys = range(p1[1] + 1, p2[1]) or [p1[1]]
    return [(x,y) for x in xs for y in ys]

print points_between((1,1), (5,1))
# [(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]

print points_between((5,6), (5,12))
# [(5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 11)]
```

Comment: This won't work correctly if a first coordinate is higher than the corresponding second coordinate.

Comment: Worked great! Just had to add in a small line to test which one is higher. Thanks.

Comment: And if the problem is vaguely interesting and I have a few spare minutes, I might provide an answer.  I'm not interested in enforcing other peoples' discipline or improving peoples' software skills who aren't already interested in improving themselves.  In other words, I am not going to force someone to care.  BTW I think it will be obvious that the OP didn't come up with this solution to any grader of a beginner course familiar with python.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be a beginning programmer. A general technique I find useful is to do the job yourself, on paper, then look at how you did it and translate that to a program. If you can't see how, break it down into simpler steps until you can.