# List of coordinates between irregular points in python

Tags: python, line, coordinates, maze

Imagine we have two randomly selected points between 0 and 100 for both x and y.

For example:

(95,7), (35,6)

Now using the simple pygame.draw.line() function we could easily draw a line between these points without any gaps.

My question is, how could we find a list of all the coordinates in a single pixel thick line between the two points without any gaps in the line?

Secondly, is this even possible?

I am using this list of pixel for the crack maze algorithm that needs to "shoot" another pixel while regarding any blocking walls that may interfere with its path.

http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm

By irregular, I refer to points which would not generate simple straight lines.

For example, it would be easy to find all the points between:

(0,5) and (5,5)

This has already been covered in this question:

[List coordinates between a set of coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326129/list-coordinates-between-a-set-of-coordinates)

Comment: I hope that this is not an obvious question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm should be a good starting point. Also, what do you mean by "irregular"?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). You can find a simple python implementation [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#Python). Here’s a modified version of that implementation, which, given a starting and ending point, can return a list of intermediate points:

```
def line(x0, y0, x1, y1):
        "Bresenham's line algorithm"
        points_in_line = []
        dx = abs(x1 - x0)
        dy = abs(y1 - y0)
        x, y = x0, y0
        sx = -1 if x0 > x1 else 1
        sy = -1 if y0 > y1 else 1
        if dx > dy:
            err = dx / 2.0
            while x != x1:
                points_in_line.append((x, y))
                err -= dy
                if err < 0:
                    y += sy
                    err += dx
                x += sx
        else:
            err = dy / 2.0
            while y != y1:
                points_in_line.append((x, y))
                err -= dx
                if err < 0:
                    x += sx
                    err += dy
                y += sy
        points_in_line.append((x, y))
        return points_in_line
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's an overkill but I'd just find the line equation and use a generator expression. To find the equation you can use [this example algorithm](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/linear_equation/write-equation/equation-of-line-given-two-points.php) which will return something like

```
lambda x: 2*x +1
```

With that we can do:

```
f = find_line_equation(A, B) #A B are tuples
points = [(x, f(x)) for x in range(min(A[0], B[0]), max(A[0], B[0]))]
```

This is assuming you want only integer points. You can also use this loop:

```
points = []
x = min(A[0], B[0])
increment = 0.1
while x <= max(A[0], B[0]):
    points.append((x, f(x))
    x += increment
```

Comment: Is the example algorithm the "find_line_equation" function or just some instructions on how to write the code yourself?

Comment: @user2592835 `find_line_equation` is the function you have to make yourself. It shouldn't be hard, just a bit dull. Finding line equations is elementary math...

Comment: Okay, that is fine.I was just asking- I should be able to do this.

Comment: I seem to get the errror:TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.

Comment: @user2592835 in that case, use the version with `while` and choose the increment you want.