# How to convert Tkinter line object to list of points

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI that uses the Tkinter Canvas widget to allow a user to draw a line over an image.  I would like to convert that line object to a list of points that make up that line. I'm able to get the coordinates and bounding box and other things described under the documentation, but I wasn't able to find the answer to this.

As an example, if I had a line that started at point `(0,0)` and ended at `(3,3)`, I would like a list that includes points `[(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you wanted `(0,0` and `(4,2)`?

Comment: That's the heart of the question. Tkinter can draw that line and display it, but I don't know what points that line includes.

Comment: Why is it you want the individual coordinates of the line? The reason there is not a direct way to do this is because it is somewhat useless; there are often better ways to do other things which may require the coordinates of the line.

Comment: The goal is to get the values of the pixels which lie along the line. The user will specify a transect along a natural image and then that transect will be analyzed and the data recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer posted by Luke Taylor on this post: [List of coordinates between irregular points in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930274/list-of-coordinates-between-irregular-points-in-python) effectively answers this question.

He presents a function which accurately replicates the line drawn by Tkinter given the starting and ending coordinates, both of which are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information from tkinter.